# Массив типа FILE

Tags: c++, c, файлы, динамические-массивы

заинтересовал такой вопрос, а можно ли создать массив типа FILE, допустим для n элементов, т.е:

```
FILE * array = new FILE[n];
```

И далее работать с ним как-то так:

```
fopen_s(&array[0], "fout.txt", "w");
// КОД
fclose(array[0]);
?
```

Comment: А что мешает проверить?

Comment: Сейчас под рукой нет компилятора, но я думаю, что будет ошибка при открытии. Поэтому решил спросить, чтобы потом не тратить время.

Comment: Можно, но только не массив `FILE`, а массив `FILE *` (и лучше переходите сразу на POSIX и Си)

Comment: @avp, ответы - в ответыю.

Comment: @insolor, покажите мне в си оператор new... и ответ написан на с++

Comment: @こきん а, теперь увидел, действительно. По поводу ответа - если вопрос на языке A, а ответ на B, то это не значит, что нужно в вопрос добавлять метку языка B. Но это не наш случай, да.

Answer (score 1):

В QT отработало нормально:

```
FILE* fff[5];

int main()
{
    for(auto a = 0; a<5; ++a){
        fff[a] = fopen("fout.txt", "w");
    }

        // КОД

    for(auto a = 0; a<5; ++a){
        fclose(fff[a]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```